# PostgreSQL: How to create cursor based pagination with sorting of aggregation results and id?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination, aggregate-functions

I want to create a cursor based pagination feature for GraphQL. Below is the data without pagination.

```sql
SELECT 
    "Post"."id",
    COALESCE(SUM("PostVote"."value"), 0)::int as "voteScore"
FROM "Post"
LEFT JOIN "PostVote" ON "PostVote"."postId" = "Post"."id"
WHERE "Post"."questionId" = 28
GROUP BY "Post"."id"
ORDER BY "voteScore" DESC, id ASC
```

| id | voteScore |
| --- | --- |
| 32 | 2 |
| 30 | 0 |
| 31 | 0 |
| 33 | 0 |
| 34 | 0 |
| 29 | -1 |

When I try to implement cursor based pagination with LIMIT 2 and id (cursor) after 30, it produces incorrect results.

```sql
SELECT 
    "Post"."id",
    COALESCE(SUM("PostVote"."value"), 0)::int as "voteScore"
FROM "Post"
LEFT JOIN "PostVote" ON "PostVote"."postId" = "Post"."id"
WHERE "Post"."questionId" = 28
    AND "Post"."id" > 30 -- new
GROUP BY "Post"."id"
ORDER BY "voteScore" DESC, id ASC
LIMIT 2 -- new
```

| id | voteScore |
| --- | --- |
| 32 | 2 |
| 31 | 0 |

My expected results are:

| id | voteScore |
| --- | --- |
| 31 | 0 |
| 33 | 0 |

How do you maintain the order without pagination like the first table above? The query I created seems to only care about the id, not caring about the aggregated data, voteScore. Basically I want to sort them by "voteScore".

Comment: Sample input data would help immensely. I can't see how the above code would give you such a resultset

Comment: You *are* sorting them by voteScore.  what you are not doing is filtering them by voteScore.  So do that.  Since it is an aggregate, you will have to do it in a HAVING clause not the WHERE.  Or just use OFFSET in the first place.  "cursor-based" pagination is generally for efficiency, but this isn't going to be efficient anyway

Comment: `ORDER BY "voteScore" DESC, id ASC` shouldn't that be just `ORDER BY id ASC` according to your requirements?

Comment: @jjanes If the table is indexed by `id` then the results can stream in pre-sorted, so this is a perfectly decent implementation of Keyset Pagination, assuming the `ORDER BY` is fixed as mentioned.

Comment: @Charlieface, Both his initial code and his first example output makes it clear he only wants to sort by id within ties of the aggregate, not as the first key of the sort.  He could make it faster as you suggest, but only by doing a fundamentally different operation than the one he wants to do.

Comment: @jjanes How does that square with the expected results, where the `id` seems to be the only determinate?

Comment: @Charlieface Therefore I asked, so that the results were as I expected.

Comment: @Charlieface His expected results shown at the bottom is just the second page of the results set he shows for the unpaged query.  It can't independently illustrate a dependence on the aggregate, as in that page they are all tied, but in the context of the unpaged result set it does show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't filter unconditionally on `id >30`, because then you will miss the row for 29 when the paging gets that far.  So you need to apply the id filter only within ties of the aggregate:

```
SELECT
    "Post"."id",
    COALESCE(SUM("PostVote"."value"), 0)::int as "voteScore"
FROM "Post"
LEFT JOIN "PostVote" ON "PostVote"."postId" = "Post"."id"
WHERE "Post"."questionId" = 28
GROUP BY "Post"."id"  
HAVING COALESCE(SUM("PostVote"."value"), 0)::int <0 or COALESCE(SUM("PostVote"."value"), 0)::int =0 and id >30
ORDER BY "voteScore" DESC, id ASC
LIMIT 2
```

You could make this slightly cleaner by using a tuple comparison, but since they are sorted in different directions that won't work without some trickery.

```
SELECT
    "Post"."id",
    COALESCE(SUM("PostVote"."value"), 0)::int as "voteScore"
FROM "Post"
LEFT JOIN "PostVote" ON "PostVote"."postId" = "Post"."id"
WHERE "Post"."questionId" = 28
GROUP BY "Post"."id"
HAVING (COALESCE(SUM("PostVote"."value"), 0)::int,-id)  < (0,-30)
ORDER BY "voteScore" DESC, -id desc
LIMIT 2;
```